# set transaction_subject PayPal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Does anyone know how to set the transaction_subject in the return IPN from PayPal.

At the moment it is returning with the same content as my custom field even though the PayPal doc's say the following:

"Pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which buyers do not see.
Default – No variable is passed back to you. "

I need this to be different from the custom field because the transaction_subject is showing in the email that the buyer gets, which means they are seeing the contents of the custom field.

Thanks

Comment: You have to post the variable custom="some_value". The variable transaction_subject will be "some_value".

Comment: I'm curious if you ever got down to the bottom of this? Passing the custom field back to the buyer in their confim email as the transaction_subject is a horrible security issue - did PayPal take it seriously and fix it? As of 2/2013 I still see custom being injected into transaction_subject via IPN.

Comment: February 2023 and the PayPal documentation STILL does not explain where the value for *transation_subject* comes from.  In my IPNs, it is an empty field.  It is definitely not being populated with the value of the *custom* pass-through variable.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the PayPal developers on [X.commerce](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018203610/https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums) do not know the purpose of the  `transaction_subject` variable or how to set it. Even PayPal's [sample IPN message *(table near bottom)*](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK) provides no notes about the variable. Finally, PayPal's [IPN & PDT Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) and [Payments Standard HTML Variable Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) do not list it.

In parsing our IPNs, `transaction_subject` always contains the value of the `custom` pass-through variable, but I am unaware that either are shown to the buyer.

Setting `transaction_subject` using NVP within the HTML form has no effect on its value.

Contact [merchant technical support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) because a "pass-through" variable displaying to the buyer is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the transaction_subject set to the value of either item_name or item_number, can't tell which, as I am setting both those to the same value. I'm *not* seeing it set to the value of 'custom', which has a different value (in fact the outgoing hosted_button_id). This is in association with `Subscribe` buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the /js/paypal-button.min.js? form method. if I set 
data-custom="{mycustomvar:3}"

the IPN result shows "transaction_subject":"{mycustomvar:3}"